# Submit compliant version of suspended app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

My app got suspended due to policy violation, but from what I've read, it seems I should be able to resubmit a compliant version:

"If you believe your app complies with our policies, please submit your app again and we’ll review your submission."  (from email below)

"If your developer credentials are still in good standing with Google Play and if your app allows for it, you can publish a new compliant version of the application." ([link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981))

But how do I do that? It seems impossible from the developer's console. I can't do anything with the suspended app, and if I create a new app it won't let me use the same name.

**EDIT**: Here is the email response after appealing (emphasis  mine):

> After further review, your app will not be reinstated because it
>   violates the ... provision of our Content Policy.
>
> Our policy states: "..."
>
> **If you publish a new version of your app**, please make sure it complies with our policies. You may want to review these resources for
>   additional guidance:
>
> Content Policy: 
>   https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#sexual-content
>
> Google Play Developer Help Center: 
>   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4450958
>
> If you believe your app complies with our policies, **please submit
>   your app again** and we’ll review your submission.

Comment: Ugh, seriously @MrsEd? This is an issue faced by a programmer on his journey to publish his programming. I'm confident there are talented programmers within this great community who may be able to help me resolve this and get back to programming.  Please don't downvote or vote to close simply for philosophical reasons. Questions like this do not hurt anybody, and will likely be helpful to some!

Comment: @MrsEd I don't take it personally, but it frustrates me. I have taken the time to give as much relevant information in the question as possible. What more would you want? I have explained the situation very clearly and it is definitely answerable (even if the answer is that it is impossible). When I find the answer I will post it here so others can benefit.

Comment: Ok but what is your app? How can we help if we do not know about its content? `After further review, your app will not be reinstated because it violates the` is pretty much a done deal. Did you try for an appeal?

Comment: Yes I know it's a done deal. Yes I tried for an appeal and that was the response.  I just want to know what's next - am I really not allowed to ever again submit an app with this name?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I'm not looking for help regarding the content or policies or anything. I know how to make it compliant, I just want to know how to submit my new compliant version to Google Play!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not in scope for SO

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unbelievably, it is actually impossible. "Submit your app again" really means "submit an app with a different package ID *and* a different name." Alternatively, you can submit under a different developer account (different package ID but name can be the same as the suspended app).

Quoting the responses from developer support:

> Unfortunately, at this time, suspended applications cannot be deleted
> from an account.
>
> Currently, we require each app have a unique title for it's default
> language. This means that you can have two apps with the same title in
> a particular language if you use a different default language and
> title for each app.
>
> For example, app A would have a title of "Android App" in it's default
> language en-US, and app B would have a title of "Android Application"
> in it's default of en-GB, but still have "Android App" as the title
> for en-US as a secondary translation.

Comment: happen to know if this is still the case?

Comment: @Greg yes its still the case. Just faced the same situation.